# How to preserve hyperlinks in r htmltable while writing to a csv/excel file?

Tags: r, html-table, hyperlink, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

There are multiple hyperlinks in an htmltable. I want those hyperlinks to be preserved while writing to a csv file.

I tried converting to a dataframe but in both cases the csv has the links expanded.

```
library(adapr)
library(htmlTable)
library(stringr)

data = data.frame("word"=c('python py', 'java'), 
                  "description"=c('Java is a statically typed and Python py is a dynamically typed',
                                  'java is a programming language'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ll <- as.list(data$word)

data$new <- data$description
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))) for(j in seq_along(ll)) {
  url <- paste0("http://www.google.com/",ll[[j]])
  url1 <- makeHyperlink(url,ll[[j]])
  url2 <- str_replace(url1,"file:///","")
  data$new[i] <- sub(ll[[j]], url2, data$new[i], ignore.case = TRUE)
}
data1<-htmlTable(data)
```

I want to preserve the hyperlinks in data1$new in csv/excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the return variable from `htmlTable` isn't a data.frame, what you get is a plain text-html-formatted-string. This is probably my biggest design mistake, back then I didn't fully understand how the S3 should be used. This conversion should have been done in the `print.htmlTable` function while the `htmlTable` only creates an object with attributes used in the `print.htmlTable`.